# Checking for item in Generic List before using it

Tags: c#, linq, list

With a generic List, what is the quickest way to check if an item with a certain condition exists, and if it exist, select it, without searching twice through the list:

For Example:

```
if (list.Exists(item => item == ...))
{
    item = list.Find(item => item == ...)
    ....
}
```

Comment: and if item != null you're golden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use `Find` once and compare the result with `default(T)`, or if `default(T)` could be the item itself, use [`FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) and check whether the index is -1:

```
int index = list.FindIndex(x => x...);
if (index != -1)
{
    var item = list[index];
    // ...
}
```

If you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, it's more idiomatic to use LINQ - again, if `default(T)` isn't a problem, you could use something like:

```
var item = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x....);
if (item != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Using LINQ will let you change from `List<T>` to other collections later on without changing your code.

Answer (score 5):

```
item = list.Find(item => item == ...);
if(null != item)
{
   //do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if `null` is a valid value you might be looking for. It also doesn't work for `List<int>` etc. Also note that there's no need to use the "constant first" approach in conditions in C#, except for situations where you're explicitly checking for equality with `bool` values.

Comment: Yes & thanks, you are right. But I don't understand your second point what difference does null != item and item != null makes?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simply with linq, just add using `System.Linq` in top of your namespace;

First if you want to get all results:

```
var items = list.Where(item=>item.Id == giveID).ToList();
```

Or if you just want first result;

```
var result = list.FirstOrDefault(item=>item.ID == givenID);
```

instead of `item.Id == givenID` you can put your own criteria. for example if item is string you can do `item == "Test"` or if is int do `item == 5`, ...

Comment: I wouldn't do `.ToList()` by default. This takes you the chance of performance profits. `.ToList()` gives you a list of the found items, whereas without that you'll get a IEnumerator to iterate through the items.

Comment: @Fischermaen I wouldn't do that, but because I see OP is not familiar with linq and deffered execution causes to ambiguity I suggest this, In all at last you should execute prepared expression tree, So without writing to list, It just makes query and didn't get you any IEnumerable (don't make mistake by what you see in compile time). You can execute it everytime you want, but should do it if you want it. it can be done by foreach loop or everything else